# Invalid Argument in Urlfetchapp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with my script when I request a post it's always returns `Invalid Arguments`. I don't know if my json parameters are causing the problem. Please help me.

```
function getWallet() {
    var header = {
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxx",
        }
    };

    var dataRequestPost = {
        "amount": 5.95,
        "email": {
            "recipient_email": "customer@acme.com",
            "subject": "Rebate has arrived",
            "message": "Thank you for using our service."
        },
        "ref": {
            "order_id": "string",
            "email": "string",
            "id1": "string",
            "id2": "string",
            "phone_number": "string"
        },
        "add_to_blacklist": false
    };
  
    var rUrl = encodeURI('https://data.seller.tools/api/v1/wallet/paypal/USD');
  
    var executeRequest = {
        'url': rUrl,
        'method': 'post',
        'payload': dataRequestPost
    };
  
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(executeRequest, header);
    var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
    Logger.log(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're including all of the right data, just not in the way expected as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params). It should be `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`, where `params` includes all other data like the method, header, and payload.

```
function getWallet() {
  var dataRequestPost = {
    "amount": 5.95,
    "email": {
      "recipient_email": "customer@acme.com",
      "subject": "Rebate has arrived",
      "message": "Thank you for using our service."
    },
    "ref": {
      "order_id": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "id1": "string",
      "id2": "string",
      "phone_number": "string"
    },
    "add_to_blacklist": false
  };
  var rUrl = encodeURI('https://data.seller.tools/api/v1/wallet/paypal/USD');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rUrl, {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxx",
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(dataRequestPost)
  });
  var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(object);
}
```